# How to chown when a user name contains a dash?

Tags: debian, user-permissions, chown

A user and group contains a dash: **abc-def**. When I try to use chown I get an error:

```
chown abc-def.abc-def * -R
chown: invalid user: `abc-def.abc-def'
```

the user is valid and it should work... how can I use chown with user/group names containing a dash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU chown uses a colon instead now to separate user and group.

```
chown abc-def:abc-def * -R
```